# Как создать экземпляр вложенного класса внутри которого есть вызов конструктора?

Tags: java, классы

Нужно создать экземпляр такого вложенного класса (причем, нельзя трогать код вне `main()` метода):

```
public class Outer {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        // код можно добавить только сюда
    }

    public static class Inner {
        Inner Inner = new Inner();

        public Inner() {
            System.out.println("Test");
        }
    }
}
```

казалось бы, экземпляр вложенного класса создается таким образом:

```
Outer.Inner inner = new Outer.Inner();
```

но вызов конструктора внутри вложенного класса все это ломает.
Как обойти эту проблему и таки создать экземпляр вложенного класса из `main()` метода?

Comment: можно просто исправить собственное сообщение, зачем это делать в ответе?

Comment: А зачем нужна строка: `Inner Inner = new Inner();`? Зачем внутри класса `Inner` создавать ещё один его экземпляр? Естественно, такой подход всё сломает, ведь он приведёт к бесконечной рекурсии при создании экземпляра `Inner`.

Comment: строка `Inner Inner = new Inner();` нужна по условиям задачи. и делать с ней ничего нельзя, как и со всем остальным кодом вне main метода. такое вот замысловатое условие, потому и обратился сюда

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer**: всё нижеописанное противоестественно, это ни в коем случае не следует применять на практике, если только вы не пишете низкоуровневые инструменты для Java-разработчиков.

Как бы странно это не звучало, но Java можно заставить создать экземпляр объекта, не вызывая *никаких* конструкторов, в том числе конструкторов его полей. Делается это при помощи проприетарного API реализации JRE от Oracle (Sun). Ключом ко всему является скрытый в дебрях проприетарного кода (и посему не описанный в документации JDK) класс `ReflectionFactory`:

```
ReflectionFactory rf = ReflectionFactory.getReflectionFactory();
Constructor objDef = Object.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
Constructor intConstr = rf.newConstructorForSerialization(Inner.class, objDef);
Inner inner = Inner.class.cast(intConstr.newInstance());
```

Теперь у нас есть экземпляр класса `Inner`, в котором все поля имеют значение `null`:

```
System.out.println(inner.getClass());    // class Outer$Inner
System.out.println(inner.inner);         // null
```

Документация из OpenJDK: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/reflect/ReflectionFactory.html

Источник: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue175.html

P. S. Вообще, задача очень странная. Либо существует более простой (но почему-то неочевидный для меня) способ её решения, либо она предназначается для крутых спецов по Java Reflections API и задаётся на собеседованиях в компании вроде [Zeroturnaround](http://zeroturnaround.com/).

Comment: Но при этом не запустится конструктор `Inner()` и не выведется строка `"Test"`, а именно это, судя по коду, и требуется.